# Detecting if user came from whatsup/viber/skype

Tags: node.js, user-agent

Is it possible to determine if a user came to your site by clicking a link shared in whatsup, viber or some other popular messenger?

They usually do send request to shared link so that they get metadata to display, and that can be determined through the user agent. However, when user actually clicks on link, unless messanger has browser built in, user agent is whatever browser they opened it in.

Using apache/nodejs/vuejs

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is impossible. When a clicked link or programmatic request invokes a web URI intent, an OS allows the user to select an app from a dialog where it can be opened. So it doesn't add any additional information to the link while opening.
Probably make sense to consider generating unique links for every application so that you know where the user comes from.

```
 https://hostname.com/home?userAgent=skype
 https://hostname.com/home?userAgent=facebook
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. That is one solution, but drawback here is that I need to generate those links. If someone just copied link on website and pasted it somewhere, without clicking e.g. "share on viber" button, I would not be able to append this query string.